# Debugging and developing environment for ROS

Tags: ros, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After watching beginnners tutorials, I still dont get where am I supposed to write code using ROS? Can I do It in QtCreator for example ? If so, how am I going to import libraries there? And how may I debug code ?
I already installed everything step by step from tutorial.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258294/debugging-and-developing-environment-for-ros/) by [commandos23](https://answers.ros.org/users/24676/commandos23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now that you know how ros works, what packages, msgs, nodes, topics are you should move on on the  public/subsc
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

create 1st a node that can publish your own msg type, lets say a frame {x,y,z} after that white a node that can receive that information, when that is working you can then edit publisher node and make a GUI for it, if ou like QT the go for QT, you can what ever you want....

About **debuging**:

if you need to debug you have a couple of options, you can in Terminal (and using ros tool suite) echoes a topic, you can too log the info to a file or to a terminal, you can use a bag(maybe too much for that purposes)

---

Originally posted by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) with karma: 424 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0